# set side by side two group of div classes

Tags: html, css

I tried to set side by side this two groups of classes, but i couldn't..
i tried to use display:flex , float:left and any other css attribute but didn't work in here.

```css
.building{
 width: 100px;
 height: 200px;
 margin:auto;
 background-color: #843533;
  border-style: solid;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.building .windowL{
 width: 30px;
 height: 40px;
 background-color: #8e8383;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 
}
.building .windowR{
 width: 30px;
 height: 40px;
 background-color: #8e8383;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 margin-left:40px;
 
}
```

```html
   <div class="building">
       <div class="windowL"></div>
       <div class="windowL"></div>
       <div class="windowL"></div>
        <div class="windowL"></div>
       <div class="windowR"></div>
       <div class="windowR"></div>
        <div class="windowR"></div>
        <div class="windowR"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want it to look like this?

So, we can just float the windows inside the building with a common class `window` and set the `margin-left` and `margin-bottom` for getting the windows aligned!

```css
.building {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #843533;
  border-style: solid;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.building .windowL{
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 background-color: #8e8383;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
  float:left;
  margin-left:7px;
 
}
.building .windowR{
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 background-color: #8e8383;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
  float:left;
  margin-left:7px;
}
```

```html
<div class="building">
  <div class="windowL"></div>
  <div class="windowR"></div>
  <div class="windowL"></div>
  <div class="windowR"></div>
  <div class="windowL"></div>
  <div class="windowR"></div>
  <div class="windowL"></div>
  <div class="windowR"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @superHero Good, let me know if you face issues implementing, if this solves your issue, dont forget to close the answer!

Comment: It is right , But I dont want to in the same div . i want do this in two similler divs

Comment: @superHero So there are two div's `windowL` and `windowR` classes! changed my answer!

Comment: @superHero Can this answer be closed? Your question is solved right?